# show no hyper link for empty data mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    if(isset($row['link']) && !empty($row['link']))
    {
        echo '<td><a href="'.$row['link'].'" target="_self\">Link name</a></td>';
    }
?>
```

using this code removes the text Link name as well from the table, but i prefer to keep the text but unlinked when ['link'] has empty value

any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
    {
        echo '<td>';
        if(isset($row['link']) && !empty($row['link']))
            echo '<a href="'.$row['link'].'" target="_self\">';
        echo 'Link name';
        if(isset($row['link']) && !empty($row['link']))
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</td>';
    }
?>
```

This logic will allow you to do much more than just output the name.  Naturally, if all you need is outputting the name, then the cleaner way would be

down vote

```
if(isset($row['link']) && !empty($row['link']))
{
    echo '<td><a href="'.$row['link'].'" target="_self\">Link name</a></td>';
} else {
    echo '<td>Link name</td>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add...

`else {
    echo "<td>Link Name</td>";`
}

seems straight forward to me...